# How to retrieve IP Address for signer by a given EnvelopeId in docusign api

Tags: docusignapi

I'm new to the docusign api, and I'm not able to find a good documentation for how to retrieve an ip address for a signer by a given envelopeid , could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Long, thanks for pointing out that this is just not fully documented but that we do have an endpoint in the DocuSign eSignature REST API that gives you the IP addresses. It's called [Envelopes::ListAuditEvents](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-soap-api/reference/status-and-managing-group/envelopeauditevents) and it lists all the events associated with the envelope. If the IP address is available - it is returned in this API call.
I'll check about improving the documentation to include the IP Address.

Comment: Hi Thank you for answering my question, however i found a api from the documentation, GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events, it seems like it returns all the audit events, and each event has a field called clientIpAddress, would this the one we can use for getting the ip?

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you Long, I'll update my answer. You are right, this is available in this endpoint. this is very interesting. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, i think this is the only one i found so far that is closest to what i want.

Comment: could you explain why you need this? I am curious to understand if this is something others may need and we should work on the documentation to make it clear